# Rails - Prevent mulitiple execution of model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent users from executing a method until it's queue/threaded has stopped running.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning if this is MRI Ruby (which? 1.8 or 1.9) or JRuby, etc. since it makes a difference.  The GIL prevents parallel execution in MRI Ruby 1.8 anyway so it's not actually possible to execute the same model method at the same time within the same process.

Comment: It is on Ruby 1.8.7....when the job runs, I don't want other user with a different session to execute the same job again. Please assist.

Comment: @ryan-bigg has the right idea with basically creating a semaphore lock on the method but you'll need to use a file based semaphore (with a reasonably long timeout) since the lock needs to prevent multiple processes from interacting at once.

Comment: Nick & Ryan, thanks for your replies. I suppose the examples in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461253/mutex-for-rails-processes would be the way to use filelocking. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define the method to check for the presence of another attribute, such as a `running` boolean attribute. If this attribute is `true`, then the method is un-usable.

Comment: Ryan, please elaborate on this idea of using a running boolean. Are you referring to setting a global constant as a boolean and toggling it to false as soon as the job is done?